# Syncfusion Scheduler Event Drag & Drop Malfunction (Angular)

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, scheduler, syncfusion

I am developing a scheduler using the syncfusion scheduler component. I have activated the drag & drop property. However it is not working always as expected. I notice that after a slight resize of the window/page (for example when i open the developer tools and slightly resize the boundary line between my page and developer tools) the drag & drop starts to miss-behave. The event under drag does not follow the mouse pointer and in some cases flickering occurs. It is interesting that after another slight resize, the drag & drop works well again. So i am suspecting something with the scheduler resizing..

Some more details:

- the issue occurs only in timeline week view and only when i customise the header to show individual days but not hours (header rows option "Date"). If i remove the header customisation it works fine again.!
- I am using node version 16.13.2
- I understand the syncfusion component version i am using (in package.json) is not the latest which also goes for the angular version. These are fixed to my project i am afraid.

I have created a minimal example which can be found in the following [git hub repo](https://github.com/pKolok/synfusion-scheduler-drag-drop-malfunction.git).

Finally, i am attaching a gif of the issue:
[Scheduler drag & drop malfunction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1bRe.gif)

Any help would be appreciated.!

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the package to version **20.3.0.47**. This version got fix with bug:

> #I405129 - An issue with Drag and drop is slow, when using eventTemplate has been fixed.

[Syncfusion Upgrade Guide](https://help.syncfusion.com/upgrade-guide/angular-ui-components?current-version=20.2.0.36&newer-version=23.1.36&type=BugFixes)